# Set distance between anchors and arrows in chemfig?

Tags: chemfig

I have the following problem:

In some of my reaction schemes, the distance between the outer boundaries of molecules and the reaction arrows is way too small, making the scheme look very crowded. How can I change this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
\schemestart
\chemfig{[:120]*6((-[:30,,,,line width=3pt])-[,,,,line width=3pt](-[:330,,,,line width=3pt](-[:35,0.8]CH_3)(-[:325,0.8]CH_3))--=(-[:210]CH_3)--)} \arrow
\chemfig{[:120]*6((-[:30,,,,line width=3pt])-[,,,,line width=3pt](-[:330,,,,line width=3pt](-[:35,0.8]CH_3)(-[:325,0.8]CH_3))--(<:[:150]H)=(<[:240]CH_3)(<:[:160]H)--)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image: chemfig arrows spacing]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thank you for providing an MWE. Great would be, if you also could add an image of your current result and maybe mark the places which you want to change. That would it make easier for others, who are currently are not that familiar with [tag:chemfig] so far.

Comment: the option is called `arrow offset`. Just set it to some value that suits you: `\setchemfig{arrow offset = 10pt}`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that in the documentation :-)